# Add css class to first child through javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is my html which is generated from a Rails form that loops through a PersonalityQuestions table.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false"   
         data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <h2>I want to be seen as successful</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <h2>I don’t want to be seen as taking up too much space </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <h2>I want to be seen as authentic and special</h2>
      </div>
```

I want to use javascript (sadly no jQuery) to add the class of `active` to the first child of my `<div classs="carousel-inner">`
The result should be `<div class="carousel-item text-center active">`

I've read every Stackoverflow post and can't find the answer.

This is the best answer I came up with
`document.getElementsByClassName('carouselinner').firstChild.classList.add('active');`

but I get an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:61`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName('carouselinner')` returns an _HTMLCollection_ which doesn't have a `.firstChild` so you get `undefined`, which is probably the cause of your error. You need to get an Element from the collection and use firstChild on _that element_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have two issues in your attempt:

Firstly, [**`getElementsByClassName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an *array-like* object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. So it is ambiguous from which index you are looking for the *firstChild*. You have provide the specific *index*.

Secondly, for an issue (***returning `#text` or `#comment` nodes***) with [**`node.firstChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)

> To avoid the issue with `node.firstChild` ***returning `#text` or `#comment` nodes***, [**`ParentNode.firstElementChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) can be used to return only the first element node. However, `node.firstElementChild` requires a shim for Internet Explorer 9 and earlier.

So your code should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-inner')[0].firstElementChild.classList.add('active');
```

But the preferred approach will be using [**`:first-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector in [**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) with [**`classList.add()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add):

```js
document.querySelector('.carousel-inner :first-child').classList.add('active');
```

```css
.active {color: red}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
      <h2>I want to be seen as successful</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
      <h2>I don’t want to be seen as taking up too much space </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center">
      <h2>I want to be seen as authentic and special</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG - thank you. I am kicking and screaming that I need jQuery, but client request is to use javascript only.  I'm realizing that I can do this without jQuery after all.